# How long will a app run if I publish it in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a question about Azure. A few days ago I got a free student subscription pack from my university on Azure. And I have a project on .Net core that needs to be hosted for a month at least. I am thinking to publish it on Azure. But I am new to Azure as well. I hardly understand how Azure works. So I need to know how long will the project run with a free student subscription pack on Azure. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think free\student azure subscription is valid for 1 year. if you are using free tier of webapp it should work for 1 year as well :)

You can follow the links to find out more about free trials. Second link also lists specific services for students to use on top of free trial.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/students/?v=18.45

Comment: Thank you very much. I will give it a try then.

Comment: Can you tell me if Azure pipeline will work the same way or not?

Comment: azure pipeline is free, but only for 240 minutes a month.